# How to find a string on a file and print right after it?

Tags: r, string, file, text

Let `path/to/file` be a path to a file that contains the string `Hello_` somewhere in the middle of tons of other characters. Using `R`, I am trying to print on this file the string `World` right after `Hello_` without erasing anything on the file.

Comment: `sed` is awesome for this kind of things, and it should be blazing fast. Do `sed -i '/Hello_/a World' path/to/file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file, add the desired text and then write the updated text to disk:

```
# Read text
file1 = readLines("pathToFile/test_file.txt")

# Add "World" after each instance of "Hello_"
file1 = gsub("(Hello_)","\\1World", file1)

# Write updated text to a new file (you can overwrite the existing file 
#  instead if you wish).
writeLines(file1, "pathToFile/test_file_updated.txt")
```